# There was an error checking the latest version of pip

Tags: python, pip

I am getting these two warning problems:
`WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip` and `WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.`

How to resolve it?

```py
C:\Users\ABDOU-ID>mysql-connector-python --version
'mysql-connector-python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\ABDOU-ID>mysql-connector-python
'mysql-connector-python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\ABDOU-ID>pip install mysql-connector-python
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\abdou-id\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9
qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages) 
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution-ip (c:\users\abdou-id\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9 _qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages)
Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector-python in c:\users\abdou-id\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundati
on.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (8.0.29) Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.0.0 in c:\users\abdou-id\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.pyth
on.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from mysql-connector-python) (4.21.1) Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\abdou-id\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9

WARNING:_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages) 
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution-ip (c:\users\abdou-id\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9
_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages)

WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution-ip
(c:\users\abdou-id\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9
qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages)

WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\abdou-id\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9
qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages)

WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
C:\Users\ABDOU-ID>
```

> WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip

> WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip

Comment: Please post your output as text!

Comment: Post the *whole* output as text, in your question, not in a comment. Please [edit] your question to include what is shown  in your picture.

Answer (score 179):

**Edit**: This issue has been fixed in pip 23.3.1. Run `pip install --upgrade pip` to install the latest version of pip.

---

This kept happening for me, even after upgrading to pip 23.3. I eventually figured out pip caches the last time it checked for updates, and the file holding this cache can be corrupted.

The following command clears pip's update cache and allows pip to check for updates the next time it is run. It does not remove cached packages.

Choose one of the following based on your operating system:

### Linux

Run this command in the terminal.

```bash
rm -r ~/.cache/pip/selfcheck/
```

### OSX

Run this command in the terminal.

```bash
rm -r ~/Library/Caches/pip/selfcheck/
```

### Windows

Run this using PowerShell.

```bash
rm -r $env:LOCALAPPDATA\pip\cache\selfcheck\
```

Comment: Thanks, deleting the cache worked for me on Windows. The corruption seems to be caused by upgrading pip in a virtual environment.

If, like me, you fear pasting a command involving `rm` you found on the Internet, you can first `cd $env:LOCALAPPDATA\pip\cache\selfcheck` , then inspect and delete.

Comment: `rm -r ~/.cache/pip/selfcheck/` this works for me in Mac.

Comment: `rm` isnt working on windows. I did `rd /s /q "%LOCALAPPDATA%\pip\cache\selfcheck\"`

Comment: @West PowerShell command.

Comment: Can confirm that OSX solution (i.e., `rm -r ~/Library/Caches/pip/selfcheck/`) worked for my M1 MacBook Pro

Answer (score 103):

You need to manually update `pip` with:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

As per discussion on the [issues page on Github](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11155)

*Edit:*

If this doesn't work, I suggest reading the following answer:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/77298334/14141223

---

This issue should now be fixed in future versions of `pip`

> [Pull request](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/11136) on Github

Comment: I have this same issue, but this command doesn't solve the problem and the issue is closed

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer If It's a different issue, or the previous solution did not fix it, i guess you could just make a new issue and explain what happened

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan Yes, you answer a different issue :-|

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: they didn't work

Answer (score 7):

It's Just a Warning for upgrading the pip you can do it with any of these commands

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Cheers  Mate
[image: Pip Installation Image]

Answer (score 5):

I use Git Bash on Windows 10, and this is the only solution that worked for me:

1. Execute this in bash: `python -m pip cache dir`
2. Open the folder returned from the output you got in step 1
3. Delete the `selfcheck` folder

You should no longer get this error.

Answer (score 4):

have you tried:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

I have macbook m2 and I've stumble on this issue.
Tried to update pip manually by:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

and

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

both did NOT solve my problem

For now, I downgrade to previous version of pip by:

```
pip install -U pip==23.2.1
```

Anytime you can check the version history from pypi.org/

Answer (score 0):

Running `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` or `pip install --upgrade pip` as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73497972/7758804) results in `SSLError ("DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC")`.

**Disconnecting my VPN allowed `pip` to connect.**

Answer (score 0):

Do check whether you have run out of disk space or not. I got this error when my disk was full and there was no space to install any new updates or packages.

Try  "df -lh" command if using an linux based environment (ubuntu, mac, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, one of these two methods can be followed.

---

1. **Clear the pip update cache:**

> Depending on your operating system, run the appropriate command to
> clear the `pip` update cache:

- On Linux:

  ```
  rm -r ~/.cache/pip/selfcheck/
  ```
- On macOS (OS X):

  ```
  rm -r ~/Library/Caches/pip/selfcheck/
  ```
- On Windows (PowerShell):

  ```
  rm -r $env:LOCALAPPDATA\pip\cache\selfcheck\
  ```

---

2. **Manually Update pip:**

> You can update `pip` using one of the following commands, depending on your preference:

- Using Python:

  ```
  python -m pip install --upgrade pip
  ```
- Using `pip` directly:

  ```
  pip install --upgrade pip
  ```

---

> **Note**: Use the appropriate command for your operating system to delete the update cache.